# Как работать с коллекцией объектов разных классов через Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Есть несколько классов 1 базовый и 3 дочерних: Person (базовый), Enrollee, Student, Teacher

Храню элементы в коллекции List:

```
public static List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
```

Нужно написать запросы для дочерних классов, например, имена студентов указанного курса, имена студентов указанного курса и т д

Как через Linq написать запрос, если объекты получаются класса Person, следовательно их нужно преобразовать в объект нужного класса, но как это сделать в запросе?

Новичок в этом деле, поэтому буду рад любому совету

Comment: `var students = list.OfType<Student>().Where(....).ToArray();`

Comment: @tym32167, ответы — в ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы используете C# 7 и выше, можно воспользоваться [*сопоставлением шаблонов типа*](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type):

```
var studentsOfGroupA = list.Where(p => p is Student s && s.Group = "A");
```

Если `p` является экземпляром класса `Student`, то конструкция `p is Student s` вернет `true` и, заодно, приведет тип и поместит приведенное значение в переменную `s`, ну и затем выполнится следующее условие. Если же `p` не является экземпляром `Student`, то конструкция вернет `false` и следующее условие, в силу ленивости оператора `&&`, проверяться не будет.

Comment: Выполняться не будет только в памяти. Трансляторы в sql протранслируют скорее всего.

Comment: Не уверен, что вообще EF примет это. Но в вопросе по него речи и не было. К тому же есть несколько реализаций наследования в EF и от этого будет зависеть конечный запрос